# Graphite not saving data to mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04, graphite

my configuration in local_settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'NAME': 'graphite',
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'USER': 'graphite',
    'PASSWORD': 'graphite',
    'HOST': '${MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR}',
    'PORT': '${MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT}',
  }
}
```

and running it with:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PYTHONPATH='/var/lib/graphite/webapp'
echo "PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH"
echo "FIXING CONFIG"
ep -v /var/lib/graphite/webapp/graphite/local_settings.py

echo "SYNCING DB"
cd /var/lib/graphite/webapp/graphite && python manage.py syncdb --noinput

echo "RUNNING GRAPHITE"
cd /var/lib/graphite/webapp/ && /usr/bin/gunicorn_django -b127.0.0.1:8000 --pythonpath=/var/lib/graphite/webapp -w2 graphite/settings.py
```

The result is that

1. All starts without problems
2. Database is created and some tables like graphite.auth_group_permissions are filled (fixtures I guess)
3. I can query for stats (I have grafana configured and stats are showing)
4. I don't see any entries in graphite.events_event (I guess here should come events with stats right?)

What am I doing wrong? Any Idea?

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd suggest removing your password from here and changing it in your configuration.

Comment: Thx for your concern but this is just a test docker container :) will work on security after it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ehhh I misunderstood:

For those who will have similar problem

- MySQL is for Django stuff (users etc)
- Stats are always stored in Whisper, which is designed specially for that purpose

If you are interested in scaling Graphite: https://grey-boundary.io/the-architecture-of-clustering-graphite/